# How to pass data retrieved from Firestore to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift

I'm trying to display some data on UICollectionViewCell which were retrieved from Firestore.

I'm using Xcode 10.2.1, swift 5.
Based on debug message, retrieving data itself seems to be successfully done; however, they don't show up on UICollectionViewCell.

"FeedVC.swift"

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView!.register(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    getDataFromDatabase()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = view.frame.width
    let height = width + 20

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return basckets.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
    cell.bascket = basckets[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

func getDataFromDatabase() {

    Firestore.firestore().collection("baskets").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else if snapshot!.isEmpty {
            print("DEBUG: Snapshot baskets is empty")
        } else {
            guard let snap = snapshot else { return }

            self.basckets.removeAll()

            for document in snap.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let documentId = document.documentID
                let bascketName = data["bascketName"] as? String ?? ""

                Firestore.firestore().collection("baskets").document(documentId).collection("items").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else if snapshot!.isEmpty {
                        print("* DEBUG * Snapshot baskets items is empty")
                    } else {
                        guard let snap = snapshot else { return }

                        self.items.removeAll()

                        for document in snap.documents {
                            let data = document.data()
                            let itemName = data["itemName"] as? String ?? ""

                            let newItem = Item(itemName: itemName)
                            self.items.append(newItem)
                        }

                        let newBascket = Bascket(bascketName: bascketName, items: self.items)
                        self.basckets.append(newBascket)

                        print("*** DEBUG *** Bascket name: \(bascketName)")
                        print("*** DEBUG *** Num of items: \(self.items.count)")
                        for item in self.items {
                            let itemName = item.itemName as? String ?? ""
                            print("*** DEBUG *** Item name: \(itemName)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

"FeedCell.swift"

```
class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var bascket: Bascket? {
    didSet {
        guard let bascketName = bascket?.bascketName else { return }
        guard let items = bascket?.items else { return }
        guard let firstItem = items[0].itemName else { return }
        guard let secondItem = items[1].itemName else { return }
        bascketLabel.text = bascketName
        itemOneLabel.text = firstItem
        itemTwoLabel.text = secondItem
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(bascketLabel)
    addSubview(itemOneLabel)
    addSubview(itemTwoLabel)
    bascketLabel.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    itemOneLabel.anchor(top: bascketLabel.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    itemTwoLabel.anchor(top: itemOneLabel.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Following is the log when I run this code:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
2019-07-20 21:44:53.074633-0700 CollectionViewAndFireStorePractice-01[52839:8976612]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2019-07-20 21:44:53.234236-0700 CollectionViewAndFireStorePractice-01[52839:8976647] 6.0.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60000000 started
2019-07-20 21:44:53.642914-0700 CollectionViewAndFireStorePractice-01[52839:8976640] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fb3eed0ed90] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-07-20 21:44:53.643541-0700 CollectionViewAndFireStorePractice-01[52839:8976640] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fb3eed0ed90] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-07-20 21:44:53.645376-0700 CollectionViewAndFireStorePractice-01[52839:8976640] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-07-20 21:44:53.645768-0700 CollectionViewAndFireStorePractice-01[52839:8976640] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-07-20 21:44:53.924874-0700 CollectionViewAndFireStorePractice-01[52839:8976647] 6.0.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see ********)
*** DEBUG *** Bascket name: 2nd Bascket Name
*** DEBUG *** Num of items: 3
*** DEBUG *** Item name: 2nd Bascket 2nd Item Name
*** DEBUG *** Item name: 2nd Bascket 1st Item Name
*** DEBUG *** Item name: 2nd Bascket 3rd Item Name
*** DEBUG *** Bascket name: 1st Bascket Name
*** DEBUG *** Num of items: 2
*** DEBUG *** Item name: 1st Bascket 2nd Item Name
*** DEBUG *** Item name: 1st Bascket 1st Item Name
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Because "DEBUG" print is showing the data retrieved from Firestore, I believe that the problem exists in how to pass the data to UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: You can use [DispatchGroup](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5371-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-2-2#toc-anchor-001).

Comment: When you get the data from firebase you should add the new objects in your array and reload your CollectionView view.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @A.Munzer . It seemed like the place I put "self.collectionView?.reloadData()" was wrong. Based on your comment, I moved this line to one layer above and it worked perfectly.